# Consolidate VMWare snapshots older then 30 days in powershell

Tags: powershell, powercli

Im trying to accomplish the above with the script below:

```
Connect-VIServer -Server ServerName01

$VMName = Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | 
    Where {$_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | select VM |
        ForEach-Object {
            $VMName.ExtensionData.ConsolidateVMDisks()
        }
```

Im quite new to PowerCLI and this is the best ive come up with so far.

I dont want to run this comand until I can see the contents of the variable $VMName so I ran the following command.

```
Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | Where {$_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | select VM
```

Which does return a list of VMNames that meet the above criteria (manual check confirms)

The initial code does not work, it doesnt pass anything at all in the $VMName variable to ExtensionData.ConsolidateVMDisks()

```
Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | Where-Object {$_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | Remove-Snapshot
```

works but i would like to see the name of the VM and the Snapshot in the confirmation window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will allow you to execute the `ConsolidateVMDisks()` method for each VM.

```
$VMName = Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | 
    Where {$_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | select VM

$VMName | Foreach-Object {
    $_.VM.Name
    $_.VM.ExtensionData.ConsolidateVMDisks()
}
```

The following will meet your requirements using the `Remove-Snapshot` command:

```
$Snapshots = Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | Where-Object {$_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}
$Snapshots | Foreach-Object {
    "VM Name: {0}" -f $_.VM.Name
    "Snapshot Name: {0}" -f $_.Name
    $_ | Remove-Snapshot
}
```

In your initial attempt, `$VMName` contains an array of VM objects. When you pipe an array into a `Foreach-Object` script block, the current object becomes `$_` or `$PSItem`. That current object is where you must access the property and corresponding methods. I added the `$_.Name` code to display the current VM name to the console before the consolidate happens. Feel free to remove it if the method already provides the output you need.

Comment: @JonDechiro, Updated.

Comment: Thanks!  This is great. Consolidation is a lot quicker than removing the snapshots.  Do you know why this is?

Comment: @DavidFolksman, that error isn't because of the code, it is either something with your environment, VM, or PowerCLI session. Maybe you could try restarting your PowerCLI session.

Comment: Also, when I remove the snapshots, there are a lot of them and i don't want to put too much a load on the hosts.  How can i get the script to only do one at a time and not time out?  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFolksman, The second code block does one snapshot at a time. Are you saying that times out?

Comment: It started over 20 different jobs in VCentre, then timed out.  The actual display in the PowerCLI console gave one VM name and one Snapshot name before it quit with a timeout error.

Comment: Some of the jobs were for the same snapshot... very odd.